# Using Mapped IDXGISurface on OpenGL

Tags: opengl, directx, rendering

can I render mapped(cpu mapped) IDXGISurface using OpenGL glMapBuffer?

```
IDXGISurface* currentSurface;
DXGI_MAPPED_RECT mapped_rect;
..
..(code that sending buffer to other process)
..
void *data = glMapBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ... );
memcpy( data, mapped_rect.pBits, size);
```

Comment: It's not clear what "render" means here. You map something from D3D. Then you pass this memory to another process. Then you try to copy that data into a buffer object. Where is the "rendering" happening in this process?

Comment: @NicolBolas I want to render actaully same surface on other process.

Comment: @NicolBolas I mean like I want to capture other process's surface (that actually render at HWND)

Comment: "*I want to render actaully same surface on other process.*" "*I mean like I want to capture other process's surface*" Those are two different things. So it's not clear where "rendering" happens. Your pseudo-code looks like it's just copying data from one process to another. The source of that data just so happens to be a DXGI surface, but it's not like the data *itself* knows that.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to say.

Comment: that surface is from IDXGISwapChain, using API Hooking. and I want to "Capture" surface and copy to other process and render with OpenGL.

Comment: to render with OpenGL*